# How to get relative ("../x") path between two files?

Tags: python, path

My directory structure is:

```
root:.
[.]
┣━[foo1]
┃  ┣━[scripts]
┃  ┃  ┗━test.py
┣━[foo2]
  ┗━test1.txt
```

I call test.py from the scripts folder and pass the entire absolute path of test1.txt

How do I get the path of test1.txt relative to the path of test.py ?

Inputs: `./foo1/scripts/test.py` and `./foo2/test1.txt`

Expected output: `../../foo2/test.txt`

Comment: Anything relevant in `os.path`? If not, add such additional information and links to the question. If nothing else, this shows initial research/attempts, which can strengthen questoins.

Comment: os.path.relpath('/foo1/scripts/test.py',start='/foo2/test1.txt')

Comment: @Luv thank you! it works. Just need to flip the order: os.path.relpath(/foo2/test1.txt', start='/foo1/scripts/test.py')